# How do I get my handle function to run with the right arguments, (Django, bootstrap script)

Tags: django, command

Here is my code:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

def handle(self, *args, **options):

    main_api_header = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/"
    specific_pokemon = f"{main_api_header}pokemon/"

    for name in pokemon_names:
        pokemon_stats = f"{specific_pokemon}{name}"
        response = requests.get(pokemon_stats).json()
        Pokemon.objects.create(
            [
                Pokemon(name=f"{pokemon_stats}{['name']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    front_normal_image=f"{pokemon_stats}{['sprites']}{['front_default']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    front_shiny_image=f"{pokemon_stats}{['sprites']}{['front_shiny']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    hp=f"{pokemon_stats}{['stats']}{[0]}{['base_stat']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    attack=f"{pokemon_stats}{['stats']}{[1]}{['base_stat']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    defense=f"{pokemon_stats}{['stats']}{[2]}{['base_stat']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    speed=f"{pokemon_stats}{['stats']}{[5]}{['base_stat']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    ability_One=f"{pokemon_stats}{['abilities']}{[0]}{['ability']}{['name']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    ability_Two=f"{pokemon_stats}{['abilities']}{[1]}{['ability']}{['name']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    type_One=f"{pokemon_stats}{['types']}{[0]}{['type']}{['name']}"),
                Pokemon(
                    base_experience=f"{pokemon_stats}{['base_experience']}")
            ]
        )
```

With the above, I am getting the data I need, but if I run it like this, it says:
TypeError: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
(self, *args) gives me:
TypeError: handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbosity'
(self) gives me:
TypeError: handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbosity'

I think you get the idea, but I've been trying different arguments, and none of them work. Is it my syntax? Or is this not the way I can make this happen?

Comment: Can you post code for your Pokemon model?

Comment: I was going to, then I figured out what happened, so tried it, and fixed my issue. BOY was I doing that ALL wrong lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize what I was doing 100%, but I was guestimating based on a bulk create I'd done before on a previous, recent project, and kinda tried to model it on that. Soon as I realized what I did wrong, it worked. Whoopsie! But I got it!

I just had to change the create() to have all my fields and get rid of the list, and put my properties in one Pokemon. Learned that lesson!